# Deviseの登録完了メールをカスタマイズしてみたいのですが，555 5.5.2 Syntax errorが出て送信できません．

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, devise

[Action Mailerとdeviseをつかって登録完了メールを自動送信してみる](https://qiita.com/mi-1109/items/974c03776eba61146aa4)

上記の記事を参考に，自作アプリ内での登録完了メールをカスタマイズしてみたいのですが，新規登録画面にアドレスなど書いて送信した後に以下のエラーを出されてしまいました．正しく動いていれば，画面が遷移して，記入したメールアドレスに本登録してください，的なメールが来るはずです．

**555 5.5.2 Syntax error. xxx - gsmtp**

エラーの場所は以下のコントローラーになってます．

**app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

　#ここから

  #qiita-ActionMailer参照
  def create
    #スーパークラス(devise)のcreateアクションを呼ぶ
    super
    #WelcomeMailerクラスのsend_when_signupメソッドを呼び、POSTから受け取ったuserのemailとnameを渡す
    WelcomeMailer.send_when_signup(params[:user][:email],params[:user][:name]).deliver
  end

　#ここまで

  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

記事にあるような，Deviseのカラム（name, email）はすでに追加してあり，githubにあげた際の保守性のために，記事内の”おまけ”の章も設定し，ターミナル上で動作確認済みなのですが，”構文エラー”がなぜ出てしまうのでしょうか？

参考までに記事をもとに追加したファイルを載せておくので，アドバイスをいただけると嬉しいです．

**config/env/development.rb**

```
#追加分or変更分
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  #qiita-ActionMailer--
  #Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    port:                 587,
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    domain:               'smtp.gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV['WELCOME_MAILER_ADDRESS'],
    password:             ENV['WELCOME_MAILER_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'login',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: `555 5.5.2 Syntax error. xxx - gsmtp` は、どういう操作をしたときにどこに出たエラーメッセージでしょうか。

Comment: すいません．新規登録画面にアドレスなど書いて送信した後にこれが出ました．正しく動いていれば，画面が遷移して，記入したメールアドレスに本登録してください，的なメールが来るはずです．

Comment: ブラウザの上でエラーが表示されたということですかね。`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` にしているので、メール送信エラーで Ruby 側もエラーが出て Rails の用意しているエラー画面が出た、とかですかね。なるほど。

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージにあるように、これは gsmtp、つまり Gmail の SMTP サーバーが構文エラーを出しているメッセージです。詳細: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=ja

したがって、メールの本文やヘッダーに問題があります。質問文に記載が無いので詳細は分かりませんが、実際に送ろうとしているメールデータを、view を確かめたり生成されているデータを確かめたりすることで確認してみてください。

生成されているデータを確かめるには、単に puts してみたり、ActionMailer のメールプレビュー機能
https://railsguides.jp/action_mailer_basics.html#%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC を使ったりなどの方法があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！本文とかそっちですね、確認してみます！夜になりますが、追記しておきます！

Comment: 遅くなりました．教えていただいたプレビューなどみてみましたが，うまいこといかなかったので，もう一度最初からやり直してみることにしました．おそらくルーティング周りの記述がおかしかったのかなと思います．アドバイス頂き，ありがとうございました！

Comment: ルーティングがおかしかったのであればそもそもメールを送れず gsmtp からエラーが返ってくることもなさそうなので、たとえばメールの内容に変な文字が入っていたとか打ち間違いがあったとかサンプルデータとして用意したメールアドレスが不正だったとかだったかもしれませんね。解決して良かったです。

Comment: 問題自体を解決できたわけではないのですが、知恵を貸していただきありがとうございました。いずれにせよ、後々取り組むのでその点に注意しながら再チャレンジします！

Answer (score 2):

たとえばToやFromのメールアドレスが不正なときに出るようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321346/555-5-5-2-syntax-error-gmails-smtp

SMTPの通信内容を確認するとエラーの詳細が分かると思いますが config.action_mailer.logger を設定することで何か得られるのではないでしょうか
https://railsguides.jp/configuring.html#config-action-mailer-logger

Comment: ありがとうございます、後で設定して確認してみます！それでまたわからなければ追記します！

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます．loggerを追加してみましたところ，おそらくルーティング周りがおかしかったみたいです．一旦やり直してほかを先に進めてからまたやってみます．ありがとうございました．